# OpenCart problem checkout/checkout -> payment_address.zone_id

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I have one problem, so where's the checkout/checkout I have one selector. There is "selected" automatic one value "Cluj", I want "selected" to appear instead of "cluj" as in the template below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZMis.png)

I want to appear --Selectati--:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWOFB.png)

I watched the code and Cluj is ("selected="select"). How I can fixed this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ddaE.png)

I can't find the problem. It's very easy I guess, but I don't know where is